Are there alternatives to bind mounts, that don't require the target already exists?
RootFS is read-only and I'm working around that by bind mounting files and directories to specific locations. Bind mounts seem to require, that the target exists already, so I can't use them to create new files or directories.
OverlayFS is not available.
I could bind mount over the parent directory, but then I would have to provide a copy of all the contents.
That solution could lead to problems when updates change rootFS or when files are accessed while the bind mount is created leading to programs loading potentially incompatible files.
Since I want the created files and directories to be writable, programs, that weren't able to write to specific areas are suddenly able to do so, resulting in unpredictable behaviour.
Does somebody know any solution, that would enable bind mounts or something similar to non-existing destinations?
